# Android create a new Object from findViewById vs casting a findViewById

Tags: java, android, view

I try to set the text from a TextView in java: first I created a object like this:

```
//Property info
TextView propertyInfo = (TextView) info.findViewById(R.id.info);
propertyInfo.setText(getInfo());

//production
TextView production = (TextView) info.findViewById(R.id.production);
production.setText(getProduction());
```

later I tried the same thing but this time I just casted it instead of creating a new Object:

```
//Property info
((TextView) info.findViewById(R.id.info)).setText(getInfo());

//production
((TextView) info.findViewById(R.id.production)).setText(getProduction());
```

In my test I found out that the second method used less memory when I called it.
I know why, however, I want to know what the correct way to do this is or how you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two methods are essentially doing the same thing.

If you need to make repeated use of the `TextView` by setting multiple properties or events the first method is better to avoid multiple calls to `findViewById`. It is also necessary if you need to keep a reference to the `View` to update later in some other method.

If you are only using the `View` once as in your case I personally prefer option two since it is more concise.

It is also worth noting that in your first method you really are not creating a new `Object`. You are only casting the returned `View` object the same as your second method.